# Easiest way to update mysql database?

Tags: mysql

What's the easiest way to update an old database structure on my server with a new one from my localhost? Both have similar structure/tables, but I would like to update the old one.

My localhost is full of erroneous data, but I would like to update the server database with an updated structure. Is there a simpler method then going through tables one by one? Sort of like a git merge

EDIT:
To be more specific, if I have a table with a structure

table - id, name, title, phone, email (old)

to be updated to

table - id, name, title, phone, email, age, sex (new)

and i have multiple tables like this in my database, is there a sort of merge function where I can update the structure of the old database to include new table fields?

(btw. im not calling mysql statements from code. I want to modify the table structure itself, maybe via phpmyadmin)

Comment: "Alter table" is a Pop Favorite?  What exactly is your question?  What exactly do you mean by "full of erroneous data"?  And how do you believe that "updating the server database with an updating structure" will somehow help?  Please be more specific.

Comment: the point of erroneous data was just that I don't want to delete the old database, and just use the new database :)

Comment: Be sure to back up your data somewhere first. (The `mysqldump` command-line tool is an excellent tool.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the SQL syntax for [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html). For example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN new_column1 VARCHAR(255),
  ADD COLUMN new_column2 INTEGER;
```

[Edit]
Hint: To see what columns need to be changed/added to sync your old and new databases, you can save a `mysqldump` of the old and new schemas to different files and then use a `diff` tool to compare them (note: only use the schemas, not the full data dumps). As you make incremental changes to the old database, the two schema dumps will look more and more alike. When you've gotten them exactly alike, you've won!

Answer (score 0):

Write SQL code that performs the necessary update - there is no magic button. Which is why you should get the DB schema right from the start although this is not always possible. Image having to reorganize a 10 billion rows and the time it would take.